# If Statement - Condition Length Greater Than 1

Tags: r, if-statement

I have two columns (`df$Z` and `df$A`)

I basically want to say: if df$Z is less than 5, then fill `df$A` with an `NA` and if not then leave `df$A` alone. I've tried these things but am not sure where I'm going wrong or what the error message means.

```
if(df$X<5){df$A <- NA}
```

Error:

> In if (df$X < 5) { :  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I also tried to do something more like this.

```
for(i in dfX){
if(df$X<5){
df$A <- "NA"
 }
}
```

Comment: Searching the internet for the error message should have been enlightening.

Answer (score 6):

No if statement needed. That's the magic of vectorization.

```
df$A[df$Z < 5] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is the `"is.na<-"` function:

```
is.na(df$A) <- df$Z < 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The vectorized form of the `if` statement in R is the `ifelse()` function:

```
df$A <- ifelse( df$X < 5, NA, df$A )
```

However, in this case I would also go with @mark-heckmann's solution.

And please note, that `"NA"`is not the same as `NA`.