# R if/else in function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I'm trying to get the following function to work for windsorizing attributes but I can't get the if elseif working in a function.  It gives the following error: "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".  I'm hoping someone can suggest a solution or alternative.

Example:

```
x <- data.frame(runif(100, 0, 100))
colnames(x) <- "test"

WINSORIZE <- function(x){
  WIN_MEAN <- mean(x)
  WIN_SD <- sd(x)
  WIN_UPPER <- sum(WIN_MEAN + (3 * WIN_SD))
  WIN_LOWER <- sum(WIN_MEAN - (3 * WIN_SD))
  if(x > WIN_UPPER){ 
    WIN_UPPER
  } else if (x < WIN_LOWER) {WIN_LOWER
    } else x
}

WINSORIZE(x$test)
```

Comment: Use `?ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380563/if-statement-condition-length-greater-than-1

Comment: The key point is that `ifelse` is vectorized while `if` is not. You can think of `ifelse` as a function that changes elements of a vector into other elements based on a binary rule. And think of `if` as just for controlling the flow of your code.

Comment: I seem to recall benchmarking this at one point and direct indexing seemed to outperform using nested ifelse statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Use R's immanent vectorized ability. Select by `[` and change the value by `<-` assignment.

This solution is very `R`-ish:

```
winsorize <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  u <- m + 3 * s
  l <- m - 3 * s
  x[ x > u ] <- u      # select elements > u and assign to them u in situ
  x[ x < l ] <- l      # select elements < l and assign to them l in situ
  x                    # return the resulting vector
}
```

And also this solution  is very `R`-ish with the already vectorized `ifelse()` function:

```
winsorize <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  u <- m + 3 * s
  l <- m - 3 * s
  ifelse( x > u, u, ifelse( x < l, l, x))
}
```

**Solution with `sapply()`**

Another possibility is to use `sapply(x, ...)` to apply your if-else constructs on each element of x.

```
winsorize <- function(x){
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  upper <- m + 3 * s
  lower <- m - 3 * s
  # apply your if-else construct on each individual element (el) of x
  # using `sapply()`
  sapply(x, function(el) if(el > upper){ 
    upper
  } else if (el < lower) {
    lower
  } else {
    el})
}
```

Or the same with `ifelse()`:

```
winsorize <- function(x){
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  upper <- m + 3 * s
  lower <- m - 3 * s
  sapply(x, function(el) 
   ifelse(el > upper, upper, ifelse(el < lower, lower, el))
}
```

**Solution with `Vectorize()`**

Or make a function out of your `if-else` construct, vectorize this function using `Vectorize()` before you apply it on `x`:

```
winsorize <- function(x){
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  upper <- m + 3 * s
  lower <- m - 3 * s
  # define function for one element
  winsorize.one.element <- function(el) {
    if(el > upper){ upper } else if (el < lower) { lower } else { el}
  }
  # Vectorize this function
  winsorize.elements <- Vectorize(winsorize.one.element)
  # Apply the vectorized function to the vector and return the result
  winsorize.elements(x)
}
```

This `winsorize.one.element` function can be written neater by `ifelse`,
but although `ifelse` is vectorized

Comment: Thanks Gwang-Jin, this is exactly what I needed.  I appreciate the detailed examples as they help with learning alternative solutions.  Thanks again, very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome, @Ryan! I'm happy that I could help you to do a step forward ;)!